# How do you rename a library filename in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Some libraries follow different conventions for their filenames, such as the PAM libs -- `pam_unix.so`, not `libpam_unix.so`.

How do you override the target library filename in CMake to get something like `new_thing.so` instead of the default `libnew_thing.so`?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can change the Prefix, Output Name and Suffix using the `set_target_properties()` function and the `PREFIX` / `OUTPUT_NAME` / `SUFFIX` property in the following way:

Prefix:

```
    set_target_properties(new_thing PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Output Name:

```
    set_target_properties(new_thing PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "better_name")
```

Suffix:

```
    set_target_properties(new_thing PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".so.1")
```

Comment: Note that this also works with generator expressions. So, you can use `set_target_properties(new_thing PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "new_thing$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>"` to add a `d` to `new_thing` for the `Debug` build of a multi-configuration project.

Answer (score 22):

Since this has to do with the filename, **you might think to look at `install`** for the answer. (And sure enough, there's a `RENAME` clause, but that's a red herring.)

**Instead, change the `target`**, using the [`set_target_properties`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html) command.

Library targets have the built-in property, `PREFIX`. The other relevant one is `SUFFIX`. These two properties get tacked on to the target name to decide the final filename at install.

For the OQ:

```
# By default, the library filename will be `libnew_thing.so`
add_library(new_thing ${NEW_THING_SRCS})

# This changes the filename to `new_thing.so`
set_target_properties(new_thing PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Let's say you also wanted the filename to have the version:

```
# This then changes the filename to `new_thing.so.1`,
# if the version is set to "1".
set_target_properties(new_thing
        PROPERTIES PREFIX ""
                   SUFFIX ".so.${NEW_THING_VER}"
        )
```