# cmake: Multiple builds from the same source subdir possible?

Tags: build, cmake

I have a subdirectory containing Python language bindings of the project, and I want to build it for several Python version (Python 2  and 3). How can I do that?
I thought to create two bindirs from the same source first:

```
add_subdirectory(python, python2)
add_subdirectory(python, python3)
```

**[edit]** However, they need specific parameters, and so I tried to set them in advance:

```
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/include/python2.7)
[...]
add_subdirectory(python, python2)
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/include/python3.6)
[...]
add_subdirectory(python, python3)
```

However, then Cmake complains about duplicated target names.
How can I solve this? Or is there a better way to run multiple builds from the same source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `python` subdir can add multiple targets via `add_executable` or `add_library` or (`add_custom_target` and `add_custom_command`). Each target added in this manner will need a different target name so it would probably look something like this:

```
add_libary(my_python2_bindings <list_of_sources>)
add_library(my_python3_bindings <another_list_of_sources>)
```

The drawback is that both can't use the same name as the target name, which is what the ultimate file name will be based on. If that's a requirement you could use set the target properties for the [output name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038963/how-do-you-rename-a-library-filename-in-cmake) and for where it is [created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994045/copy-target-file-to-another-location-in-a-post-build-step-in-cmake).

```
 project(my_python_bindings)

 add_libary(my_python2_bindings <list_of_sources>)
 set_target_properties(my_python2_bindings PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
 set_target_properties(my_python2_bindings PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python2")


 add_library(my_python3_bindings <another_list_of_sources>)
 set_target_properties(my_python3_bindings PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
 set_target_properties(my_python3_bindings PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python3")
```

Edit: for many python versions do something like this in the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `python` subdir you would have a list containing all python versions `PYTHON_VERSION_LIST` and then

```
foreach(version ${PYTHON_VERSION_LIST})
  add_library(my_python${version}_bindings <list_of_sources>)
  set_target_properties(my_python${version}_bindings PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
  set_target_properties(my_python${version}_bindings PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python3")
endforeach()
```

But now you need to add an `if` clause for different source lists for each version. In that case its probably easier to just expand my original example to be 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6 instead of only 2 and 3.

Also, if each version is genuinely different like it sounds like they are, you probably want to think hard about giving them all the same filename.

Comment: The problem is that there are not just two fixed Python versions, but several (2.7, 3.5, 3.6 in the moment), and I wanted to put the `add_subdir` within a loop over the actual available Python versions. The problem could probably be solved by having parameterized target names, like `python_bindings_${PYTHON_VERSION}`. Is this possible?

Comment: You can also parameterize variables like this: `add_library(my_python${version}_bindings ${SRC_${version}})` to get different source lists for each case. That will expand to `add_library(my_python3.5_bindings ${SRC_3.5})`