# CMake rename executable target at install stage or create symlink

Tags: cmake

I tried multiple approaches:

1. `install(TARGETS tgt RUNTIME DESTINATION /usr/bin RENAME another_name)` ignores RENAME without any warning. Documentation says no about RENAME for TARGETS.
2. `add_executable(zbus-publish ALIAS zbus-example-publisher)` gives an error

   > `install TARGETS given target "zbus-publish" which is an alias.`
3. tried to install symlinks to installed targets

   ```
   install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ln -s zbus-example-publisher  ${DESTDIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}/zbus-publish
                                 COMMAND ln -s zbus-example-subscriber ${DESTDIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}/zbus-subscribe)
         message(==================================================)"
   ```

   But it expands DESTDIR to nothing.

I need DESTDIR because use `make DESTDIR=xxxx` to test my installation. It is very convenient. And also useful when cross-compiling.

CMake version 3.17.2

Comment: Why do you need to "rename" it on install? Why not have the desired name from the beginning? :) Please describe your case in more detail.

Comment: And JFYI, `RENAME` works for `install(FILES...)` not for `install(TARGETS...)`.

Comment: "But it expands DESTDIR to nothing." - So your **specific** problem is about handling `DESTDIR` in `install(CODE)` and not about symlinks in *general*, isn't it?

Comment: Another FYI (and a hint) `DESTDIR` is a GNU Make variable -- meaning *not CMake* :) And GNU Make pass it via **environment** to sub-processes.

Comment: One more hint: `cmake -E create_symlink  ...` is a **portable** way to make a symbolic link.

Comment: @zaufi, I a writing install procedures for already existing bundle of SW, I am not legitimate to change targets names or any source code, but few installed executables are used under other names, so I need to keep target names as is and provide other names installed. This is my case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yes, my question is not about symlinks, I simply need renamed output file (executable or lib).

Comment: Thank you guys for attention to my question. Now it is resolved.

Comment: EDIT. not resolved but workarounded

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31139717/3743145)

> You can change the Prefix, Output Name and Suffix using the set_target_properties() function and the PREFIX / OUTPUT_NAME / SUFFIX property in the following way:
>
> Prefix:
>
> ```
> set_target_properties(new_thing PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
> ```
>
> Output Name:
>
> ```
> set_target_properties(new_thing PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "better_name")
> ```
>
> Suffix:
>
> ```
> set_target_properties(new_thing PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".so.1")
> ```

This is not exactly what I looked for. But works in special case.
I'd like to keep `OUTPUT_NAME`s as is and create symlinks during `install`.